# Make the code below .then fire even if there is an error

Tags: discord.js

I have a kick command in my discord.js bot, and I wanted to make the bot send a DM to the person that got kicked. I can not do it like this:

```js
user.send(message)

                    
target.kick(reason).then((m) => {
   // do the other stuff here
});
```

With this code, the DM does not get sent.
This is what I did instead:

```js
user.send(message).then((msg) => {              
   target.kick(reason).then((m) => {
      // do the other stuff here
   });
});
```

Now the issue is that if the target blocks the bot, the bot can not DM them, making the code to kick them not run.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.finally`, which runs regardless if the promise is fulfilled or rejected.

```js
user.send(message).finally(() => {              
   target.kick(reason).then((m) => {
      // do the other stuff here
   });
});
```